Can a Medusa see though the snakes in its 'hair'?
If a Medusa closes the eyes on its face or is blindfolded, can it still see through the eyes of the snakes growing out of its head? And if so, can it use this sight to get around the vulnerability to its own petrifying gaze?

Unclear, but probably not.
In the entry for Medusa (MM, p.214) it talks about "medusa's eyes", yet it is not clear whether it's talking only of the two eyes set on its face (seen in the picture), the eyes on the snakes, or both.
At my table and when I've played at others tables there was an assumption that the Petrifing Gaze was as a result of the central eyes in the face.
You can decide as a DM that all eyes on the medusa, including the serpents can potentially petrify. However, I'd suggest being consistent, i.e. in the scenario where the Petrifying Gaze can be delivered by the serpents, the medusa would have to blindfold all its eyes.
There is not indication that the medusa can see through the eyes of the serpents and that the Petrifying Gaze is only effective if the creature looks at medusa's central eyes. However, this kind of goes against the lore of the monster. In the information about medusa it states that: "[...], after years of the living like a demigod among mortals, the price for their vanity and hubris is exacted, and they are forever transformed into medusas."
There is a poetic justice in that a creature of such vanity turns into a medusa and no longer be able to see its own reflection and beauty. Not only that, it is doomed to live "in seclusion, alientated" from all those who admired and loved it.
If you allow the medusa to see through its serpent eyes (without imminent petrification) it will be able to see its own reflection in a mirror which spoils the lore (for me).

-1 for the last paragraph.  Unsubstantiated opinion: seeing her form through the hundreds of snake eyes could be additional torture.

@Trish I'm not sure about your point. The lore does not fit your suggestion. It's still a great suggestion as a punishment/effect for being so vane, e.g. that you need to see your now monstrous self all the time through your myriad snake eyes. But, that simply isn't the case in the information for medusa in the 5e Monstrous Manual.
